# VSCODE build error `The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'yarn run watch-extensionsd'" failed to launch (exit code: 127).`

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, build, yarnpkg

I want to build VSCode from source and I get this error:

> `The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'yarn run watch-extensionsd'" failed to launch (exit code: 127).`

Comment: Hi, do you use MacOs or Linux with zsh? Is yarn installed? Do you have the script "watch-extensionsd' (including the d at the end) in the package.json?

Comment: @MarkusMadeja MacOS and yarn is installed and it is in the package.json

Answer (score 45):

The problem is your npm scripts in vscode is started with `/bin/zsh -c` (non-login non-interactive)
This means scripts inside ~/.zshrc is not executed (and for the same reason ~/.zprofile).
However, even in non-login non-interactive mode, ~/.zshenv is loaded.

Solution 1:

```
Change "npm.packageManager": to npm
Make sure you restart vscode to make this take into effect.
```

Solution 2 (preferred):

```
Open ~/.zshrc and move whatever scripts that is loading yarn into ~/.zshenv
```

In my specific case, my yarn is installed through npm `npm i -g yarn` and my npm is installed through nvm. So I had to move following two lines.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Solution 3:

Don't use VSCode's npm scripts. You can actually execute by opening terminal yourself shortcut ctrl + ` and typing out yarn "npm script name".

Comment: create a ```~/.zshenv```
add a line ```source ~/.zshrc```

Comment: solution 2 works like a charm on linux, thank you

Answer (score 11):

On macOS, I addressed this by locating the `inheritEnv` option in VS Code settings.

Alternatively, you can include this line in your `settings.json`: `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false`.

Comment: Thanks! This works for me for a similar problem!

Comment: Would you please elaborate your answer?  In settings.json, add this string: "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false

Answer (score 6):

Related to the above, if macOS and your computer recently *restarted on its own* (e.g., kernel panic), I found that VScode reloads improperly without loading the environment in all Terminals that were open prior.

**The fix is simply to close out of VSCode completely, then relaunch**. The environments will then load properly.

Answer (score 3):

It happens that `~/.zshrc` is not sourced when VS Code is launched from the application menu but if it is launched from a terminal it works perfectly. So what I did is, I changed the command of `Exec` field in the desktop entry file (`/usr/local/applications/code.desktop` or `~/.local/share/applications/code.desktop`) to `zsh -c "source $HOME/.zshrc && code"`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it's happening when I try to use `nx` plugin for VS Code.
So the only thing I needed to do is restart VS Code and it's working again.

Answer (score -2):

In my case,
I just commented out a setting in VS Code. It works.

```
"files.exclude": {
  "node_modules/": true
},
```

Comment: This above did not work for me.