# VS code Docker extension unable to "attach shell"

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

When I try to right click -> attach shell on any of my docker boxes, a terminal windows opens and outputs the following:

```
 *  Executing task: docker exec -it <container_id> bash 

zsh:1: command not found: docker

 *  The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'docker exec -it <container_id> bash'" failed to launch (exit code: 127). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

When I run `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` manually, it works. The "attach shell" dropdown option just doesn't work. Why?

I've tried changing my default terminal to bash with no luck. I'm on Mac Monterey 12.1 with the M1 chip. With some digging I found a thread that mentioned this could be an issue with Mac but that thread was using a different OS version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was related to the following answer on a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65304142/9731043

"your npm scripts in vscode is started with /bin/zsh -c (non-login non-interactive) This means scripts inside ~/.zshrc is not executed (and for the same reason ~/.zprofile). However, even in non-login non-interactive mode, ~/.zshenv is loaded."

In my case it was my path variables.

To fix I followed

```
Open ~/.zshrc and move whatever scripts that is loading yarn into ~/.zshenv
```

Copy the path variable that contains `docker` into ~/.zshenv.

`~/.zshenv`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: lmaooo. Well, this is an interesting issue. How did the OP know that ```~/.zshenv``` was loaded?